# Get first value or default from json object in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tried this code:

```
DECLARE @json_doc nvarchar(4000) = '{"Name1":"Value1", "Name2":"Value2"}';

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENJSON(@json_doc)) > 0
    THEN JSON_VALUE(@json_doc,'$.' + (SELECT TOP(1) [key] FROM OPENJSON(@json_doc))) 
    ELSE NULL END
```

But it gives me this error:

> Msg 13610 Level 16 State 1 Line 3
>   The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.

Anyone know how to get this element?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Value1 in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @json_doc nvarchar(4000) = '{"Name1":"Value1", "Name2":"Value2"}';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  [Value], 
            -- row number is ordered by the keys first appearence in the json source.
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CHARINDEX('"' + [Key] +'":', @json_doc)) As rn
    FROM OPENJSON(@Json_doc)
) 

-- Get the value if json_doc contains any value
SELECT [Value] As ValueOrDefault
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1

UNION 

-- Get null if not
SELECT NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE);
```

The result of this query would be `Value1` for that json.
However, if the `@json_doc` would be empty (`set @json_doc = '{}';`) it will return `NULL`.

[<kbd>DB<>Fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3af8e60376cbb025429cbeefb9ce5b7b)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
DECLARE @json_doc nvarchar(4000) = '{"Name1":"Value1", "Name2":"Value2"}';
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
DECLARE @json_doc nvarchar(4000) = ''' + @json_doc + ''';
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENJSON(@json_doc)) > 0
    THEN JSON_VALUE(@json_doc,''$.' + (SELECT TOP(1) [key] FROM OPENJSON(@json_doc)) + ''') 
    ELSE NULL END
';
EXECUTE (@sql);
```

Comment: `OPENJSON` returns a table, and tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature. Because of that fact, using `TOP(1)` without an `ORDER BY` clause actually means "get me an arbitrary row". Note that arbitrary is not the same as random. Granted, that code is copied from the code in the question, but still that doesn't mean it doesn't have a problem (or two)